# How to implement a search function for email address in a JSON object and store the result in a Vue.js grid table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

JSON return stored in data.userRegistrationDatas, how i search whole Object for email address and only match email address is can be stored in userRegistration.GridTable[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igQs7.png)

I tried forEach look . I want to search email address by entered email address in a JSON result and stored in Grid table

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this?

```
userRegistration.GridTable.value = data.userRegistrationsDatas?.find(d=>d?.Email=== 'emailWhatYouAreLooking');
```

see how to get one specific element in a array : [javascript find function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)